# Como atualizar coluna para cada SELECT em determinada tabela?

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang, plpgsql

Tentei criar uma `trigger` para uma tabela usando para que ela fosse ativada após cada `select`, mas pesquisando um pouco descobri que não é possivel criar `triggers` para seleções, apenas para atualização (update), inserção (insert) e deleção (delete).

Minha aplicação é uma api e a mesma esta apresentando problemas em teste de Benchmark; toda vez que faço um `select` eu tenho uma outra função que executa um update e incrementa uma coluna desse registro selecionado. O problema é que muitos updates ao mesmo tempo estão causando este erro:

> sorry, too many clients already

Foi ai que pensei em criar uma `trigger` direto no banco de dados para não ter que executar um `update` via código a cada `select`.

Este foi o código que criei em `plpgsql` para tentar incrementar a coluna:

```
create table urls(
    id integer not null,
    url varchar(255) not null,
    encoded varchar(255) not null UNIQUE,
    clicks integer DEFAULT 0,
    created_at timestamp not null DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    constraint pk_urls_id primary key (id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_clicks_counter()
    returns trigger as
        $BODY$
            BEGIN
                UPDATE urls SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE encoded = OLD.encoded;
            END;
        $BODY$
language 'plpgsql';

CREATE trigger increment_clicks AFTER SELECT ON urls
    for each ROW EXECUTE procedure increment_clicks_counter();
```

Como posso criar uma rotina para incrementar uma coluna a cada seleção de uma determinada tabela?

Este é o Benchmark que estou executando em `GO`:

```
func BenchmarkAPI(b *testing.B) {
    // Valores que estão presentes na coluna 'encoded' da tabela urls
    random := []string{
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "H", "F", "E", "G",
        "8", "5", "9", "6", "7", "2",
    }

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        url := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:5000/%s", random[rand.Intn(len(random))])

        _, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            b.Log(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente (ou felizmente), em `PostgreSQL` não existem `TRIGGERS` do tipo `AFTER SELECT`.

Porém, você pode resolver o seu problema "encapsulando" sua tabela em uma *stored procedure* escrita em `PL/pgSQL`.

Essa *stored procedure* seria capaz de recuperar os dados da tabela e depois gravar essa atividade em uma outra tabela específica, a tabela não poderia ser acessada diretamente e seus dados só seriam recuperados por meio dessa função de encapsulamento.

Considere a seguinte estrutura/dados:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pessoa
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
    sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tb_log
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    tabela TEXT NOT NULL,
    operacao TEXT NOT NULL,
    diahora TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( id, nome, nascimento, sexo ) VALUES ( 1, 'JOAO',  '1980.02.10', 'M' );
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( id, nome, nascimento, sexo ) VALUES ( 2, 'MARIA', '1966.05.10', 'F' );
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( id, nome, nascimento, sexo ) VALUES ( 3, 'JOSE',  '1973.07.10', 'M' );
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( id, nome, nascimento, sexo ) VALUES ( 4, 'ANA',   '1984.03.10', 'F' );
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( id, nome, nascimento, sexo ) VALUES ( 5, 'JESUS', '1970.12.10', 'M' );
```

Essa função de encapsulamento ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_wrapper_pessoa()
RETURNS SETOF tb_pessoa AS
$$
DECLARE
    rec tb_pessoa%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR  rec IN SELECT * FROM tb_pessoa
    LOOP
        return next rec;
    END LOOP;

    INSERT INTO tb_log ( tabela, operacao, diahora ) VALUES ( 'tb_pessoa', 'SELECT', now() );

    RETURN;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

As consultas a tabela `tb_pessoa` seriam todas feitas por meio dessa função, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM fc_wrapper_pessoa();
SELECT * FROM fc_wrapper_pessoa() WHERE id = 5;
SELECT * FROM fc_wrapper_pessoa() WHERE nome = 'JESUS';
SELECT * FROM fc_wrapper_pessoa() WHERE nascimento BETWEEN '1960-01-01' AND '1969-12-31';
```

E por fim, para cada consulta feita na tabela `tb_pessoa` seria gravado um registro na tabela `tb_log`:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_log WHERE tabela = 'tb_pessoa' AND operacao = 'SELECT';
```

Saída:

```
| id |    tabela | operacao |                     diahora |
|----|-----------|----------|-----------------------------|
| 11 | tb_pessoa |   SELECT | 2018-06-14T16:06:18.073404Z |
| 12 | tb_pessoa |   SELECT | 2018-06-14T16:06:18.073404Z |
| 13 | tb_pessoa |   SELECT | 2018-06-14T16:06:18.073404Z |
| 14 | tb_pessoa |   SELECT | 2018-06-14T16:06:18.073404Z |
```

Se o que importa para você é a quantidade de consultas que a tabela sofreu:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM tb_log WHERE tabela = 'tb_pessoa' AND operacao = 'SELECT';
```

Saída:

```
| count |
|-------|
|     4 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1fcd/9)

Comment: faz todo sentido! obrigado.